# After using where condition how to get single column values without repeated values in a table in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4. I have three tables like below.

**users table**

```
id          name         username           

1           krish        krish@gmail.com      

2           kaviz        kaviz@gmail.com
```

**roles table**

```
id      role      sub_role 

1       admin     default

2       support   default

3       Hr        default

3       admin     admin_1
```

**roles_users**

```
id    user id  role id

1     1        1

2     1        2

3     1        3

3     2        2
```

**My Controller**

```
$users=Rolesusers::all();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $user_names[]=User::where('id', '=', $user->user_id)->groupby('name')->select('name')->get();
}
return $user_name;
```

**My result**

```
[
  {
    "name": "krish"
  }
  {
    "name": "krish"
  }
  {
    "name": "krish"
  }
  {
    "name": "kaviz"
  }
]
```

but I need a result without repeated values, like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "krish"
  }
  {
    "name": "kaviz"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is running for each $users value that's why it store value for each query you should change your logic or at the end you use **array_unique()** function in php hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The where clause returns a collection, so you can utilize the `unique()` method on collections.

In your case

```
  foreach($users as $user)
  {
      $user_names = User::where('id', '=', $user->user_id)->groupby('name')->select('name')->get();

  }

  $user_names->unique('name');

  dd($user_names);
```

Or, Using arrays

```
  foreach($users as $user)
  {
      $user_names[] = User::where('id', '=', $user->user_id)->groupby('name')->select('name')->get();

  }
 $user_names = array_unique($user_names);
 print_r($user_names);
```

see [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) or [eloquent collection unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique)

Comment: its working thanks for answer but its not full filled for my project becouse after above process my coding is like this

Comment: Actually  I m sorry  i m not mention my full coding structure  the structure is i posted below now. but that process not working properly using above solution. so please help me below posted coding structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do your 'groupBy' in your Rolesusers. Please try the below to answer your query,

```
    $users = Rolesusers::select('user_id')->groupBy('user_id')->toArray();
    $user_names = User::select('name')->whereIn('id', $users)->get();
    return $user_name;
```

Please note that in your code, the query runs in a loop which should be never done. Please do not run a query inside a loop.

Comment: I am sorry, I mis-understood your question & posted in-appropriate answer initially. Now, I updated my answer